# fetchedResultsController returns nil

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

Trying to create simple application to display data from Core Data to Table View. The code builds successfully - every time it loads it adds new entry, currently more than 20 - but then it crashes when trying to build the table.

Here I have ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

     @IBOutlet weak var habitTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let habitClassName:String = String(describing: Habits.self)

        let habit:Habits = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: habitClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Habits

        habit.habitsPic = ":("
        habit.positive = false
        habit.theHabit = "do bad"

        DatabaseController.saveContext()

        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Habits> = Habits.fetchRequest()

        do{
            let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
            print("number of results: \(searchResults.count)")

        }
        catch{
            print("Error \(error)")
        }

    }

    //CONSTRUCT TABLE VIEW
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)-> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
            fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
        }
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "positiveCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        let habit = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Habits

        cell.textLabel?.text = habit.theHabit
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = habit.habitsPic

        return cell
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    //FOR DISPLAYING DATA IN TABLE
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>!

    func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Habits")
        let departmentSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "theHabit", ascending: true)
        let lastNameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "positive", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [departmentSort, lastNameSort]


        let moc = DatabaseController.getContext()
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = (self as! NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate)

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

And DatabaseController:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


class DatabaseController {
    private init(){

    }

    class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{
        return DatabaseController.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }


    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ada")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

class func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

It will not build the table view, because the fetchedResultsController returns nil. I assume it is problem with "moc" variable, but what?

**EDIT**

**error**: 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**line**:
guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {

Comment: "but then it crashes when trying to build the table." And what's the error message?

Comment: When do you call your `initializeFetchedResultsController` method?

Comment: @Larme Error message: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @TomHarrington I call it in  guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {

Comment: @MartinsB Then update your sample code to make it accurate, because your question doesn't show that.

Comment: " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" That's a known issue and the message is explicit. Did you try to find out which value is nil and shouldn't be?

Comment: @Larme as I wrote - it is in fetchedResultsController and in "moc" variable.

Comment: It's highly recommended to initialize `fetchedResultsController` lazily with a closure like in the Core Data template. It guarantees that the controller is ready on the first access.

Comment: @MartinsB You do not seem to be assigning a value to `fetchedResultsController`, because you never call `initializeFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare your fetched results controller as an implicitly unwrapped optional:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>!
```

Its initial value is nil.

You also have a method called `initializeFetchedResultsController` that assigns a value to this property, but **you never call that method**.  In a comment you said that you're calling it in this code:

```
guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
    fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
}
```

But that code never mentions the `initializeFetchedResultsController` method, and so it never calls that method.

You have an optional variable but you never assign it a value. So it never gets a value. So it's nil. This isn't a Core Data question, it's basic Swift. Properties don't get values unless you give them values, and you are not doing that.